# Web browser displayes a corrupt page when attempting to download a file from my website

Tags: html, download, corrupt

Whenever users of my website click on the download button to download either a picture, video, or music, a corrupt webpage is displayed:

[image: screenshot of error]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a bit tunnel to send a binary file, but the bit tunnel (index.php) is hard-coded to send the content type as text/html. For that particular file should set the correct `Content-type` header to the correct MIME type for the data being returned. If you want the file to be downloaded instead of just displayed inline, you should also set the `Content-disposition` header. As an example:

```
Content-type: audio/mpeg3
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=foobar.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your website. The problem could be (1) an issue with the character encoding or (2) your file could actually be corrupted (e.g. hacked):

1. It would be good to specify a character encoding if you haven't done so in your HTML page. I have had similar confusion because of a wrong (or missing) character encoding. (Also, it is wise to specify a doctype. Otherwise, the browser renders using its "quirks mode," in which it makes guesses on how to render the markup, but it can make mistakes.)
2. This may not mean anything...but did you add the slightly ominous comment `<!--Hacked by -->` on line 1 in your HTML file?

Comment: i finally figured it out.the component i use for downloading files(jdownloads) wasint configured properly. their was indeed some issues with the character encoding. iv'e rectified the problem and the site is good to go...Thanks guys.